# Ninject ERROR - HELP Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.IO.FileLoadException' en Ninject.dll

Tags: c#

Alguien me podría decir como solucionar este error.

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.IO.FileLoadException' en
>   Ninject.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>
> Información adicional: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
>   'Ninject.Web.Common, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' ni una de sus dependencias. La
>   definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia
>   al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ve a la carpeta bin y elimina los archivos de Ninject que se generaron o borra toda la carpeta bin, para que te cree de nuevo las dll

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la versión de ese ensamblado tanto en tus referencias como en el archivo de configuración `web.config` sea la misma.